Custom webfont incorrectly rendered through laravel-dompdf
I'm generating a document using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. I want to use the Nunito font in my document.
My controller method:
public function generateSocialBanner(EditionUser $editionUser) {
    $domPDF = $this->documentsManager->generateDocument($editionUser);
    return $domPDF->stream();
}

The generateDocument() method:
// use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf as DomPDFFacade;

private function generateDocument() {
    $myContent = '<h1>Some text</h1>';
    $document = DomPDFFacade::loadView('documents.banner', compact('myContent'));

    // this can help with font not working properly but makes the document size a tad bigger
    $document->setOption('isFontSubsettingEnabled', false);
    // setup font configuration to allow DomPdf to compile Nunito
    $tmpDir = sys_get_temp_dir();
    $document->setOption('fontDir', $tmpDir);
    $document->setOption('fontCache', $tmpDir);
    $document->setOption('tempDir', $tmpDir);

    $document->setPaper('L');
    $document->output();

    return $document;
}

The documents/banner.blade.php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BANNER</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Nunito';
            src: url("{{ Storage::disk('public')->path('fonts/nunito/static/Nunito-Regular.ttf') }}") format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Nunito';
            src: url("{{ Storage::disk('public')->path('fonts/nunito/static/Nunito-Bold.ttf') }}") format('truetype');
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Nunito';
            src: url("{{ Storage::disk('public')->path('fonts/nunito/static/Nunito-Italic.ttf') }}") format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Nunito';
            src: url("{{ Storage::disk('public')->path('fonts/nunito/static/Nunito-BoldItalic.ttf') }}") format('truetype');
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            font-size: 13px;
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    {!! $myContent !!}
</div>
</body>
</html>

Instead of having Some text correctly rendered in Nunito font, it is replaced with strange characters:

The font is correctly loaded, as it does not fallback on the default sans-serif setting.
When I copy-paste the text, I get Some text in my clipboard.
System information:

PHP 7.4
Laravel 8
barryvdh/laravel-dompdf 2.1.1
dompdf/dompdf 2.0.3

Why do I have this problem?
Update: using only DomPDF, without the barryvdh/laravel-dompdf bridge, is working fine.

It was because of barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. As soon as I got rid of the bridge, the fonts worked properly.
